# Choosing from multiple Views, when using a HasTraits object in Item

Tags: python, traits, enthought, traitsui

Is there a way to define multiple views for a `HasTraits` object, and choose them when displaying them as an `Item`?

```
class Person(HasTraits):
    first_name = String()
    last_name = String()

    formal_view = View(
        Item('first_name'),
        Item('last_name'),
        )
    familiar_view = View(
        Item('first_name')
        )

class Family(HasTraits):
    formal_father = Instance(Person,())
    familiar_father = Instance(Person,())


    view = View(
        Item('formal_father', style = 'custom'),
        Item('familiar_father', style = 'custom', 
             view = 'familiar_view'),
        )
```

The keyword `view` in the last Item  is just to illustrate how i would expect it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you've almost got it. See 
http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/TUIUG/advanced_view.html#defining-multiple-views-within-the-model

Comment: yes a little more reading and i added, `editor = InstanceEditor(view = 'familiar_view'))` which works.  is that your suggestion?

Comment: yes, and also the view keyword when calling edit_trait or configure_traits.